# SPO / Rest API Changing TimeLastModified

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2013, rest

Is it possible to set (on upload) or modify (e.g. with a PATCH operation) the `TimeLastModified` attribute in Sharepoint 2013 / SPO via the Rest api?

I'm getting mixed signals on this one - I've tried PATCH requests that have succeeded but seemingly been ignored (whilst updating the revision). A few online examples show it being done with Powershell (which is out of the question).

The use case here is migration of existing files from another system. It's nice to preserve this metadata. An alternative might be some kind of custom field but I can't see that being useful - it would quickly get out of date and would not